# Finding the maximum load allowed in a lift.

Tags: classical-mechanics

*A lift of mass $520kg$ is supported by a steel rod attached to its bottom. The rod can withstand the maximum thrust $15,400N$. The lift can accelerate at $2.5ms^{-2}$ and decelerate at $7.8ms^{-2}$. Find the maximum allowed load in the lift.*

This question is confusing me as I am not very comfortable with the normal reaction force and any help would be appreciated. I have attached my working, but it isn’t correct, and I am unsure where I have gone wrong.

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the maximum load be $M$ kg, so the total mass (lift + load) is $520+M$. The greatest force delivered by the rod when the lift is accelerating at maximum rate is when the lift is accelerating upwards. Then we require $$15400-(520+M)g\ge(520+M)2.5$$ Similarly, for deceleration, the worst case is when the lift is decelerating at 7.8 with the rod having to overcome gravity (ie slowing down as it is coming down). We need $$15400-(520+M)g\ge(520+M)7.8\quad(*)$$ So $(*)$ is the more restrictive condition and gives $$M(g+7.8)\le15400-520g-4056$$ Taking $g=9.81$ that gives $$M=\frac{6242.8}{17.61}=354.5\text{ kg}$$ Of course, in practice one would allow a considerable safety margin, so the allowed load would be smaller.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately, the answer is apparently 355kg, not 511kg.

Comment: @Jamminermit I made a stupid arithmetical error. Now fixed!

Comment: Ah, that looks better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let "M" be the maximum load, in kilograms.  Carrying that load, the combined mass of elevator and load is M+ 520 kg.  Since "force equals mass times acceleration", F= ma, at 2.5 m/s^2 acceleration, the force is F= (M+ 520)(2.5)= 2.5M+ 1300 N. We are told that "The rod can withstand the maximum thrust 15,400N" so to find the maximum load we must solve 2.5M+ 1300= 15400.  This is done entirely in terms of mass and acceleration so I see no need to multiply by "g" to get weight.

Comment: Unfortunately, solving your equation does not yield the correct answer (unless the answer in the book is wrong). Also you haven’t used the information about the deceleration, so any idea where your solution may be wrong?

Comment: I don't see how you can ignore the force of gravity. It imposes an additional load on the rod.

Comment: Okay, I will concede I should have included the weight!